# view does not load at correct time

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The program I'm writing has a view with several tiles on it that are scrambled properly when the following code is executed:

```
    [self scrambleBoard];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

where scrambleBoard is a method I have that mixes up the tiles randomly.  The above code works correctly and shows the final scrambled position of the tiles.
The problem I have is that I want to give the program the appearance of the tiles actually scrambling, sort of like animation, but not really so, it would just show 8 consecutive different scrambled views.  So I incorporated the above code into the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{        
    [self scrambleBoard];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    usleep(250000);
}
```

The problem is that instead of showing 8 different scrambled views in succession, I only get the final scrambled view. Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance
Gil

Comment: Yep, you should never sleep in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are simply blocking the thread as a sleep is almost always the wrong thing to use on the main thread.

I believe the final view is only really calculated at the end of the runloop which will essentially just give you the result of the last jumbling.

Comment: Thank's Paul.  I created a separate thread and called it and that worked.